# メタのユーザー登録ページでSSLエラー

Tags: バグ, 完了

URL: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/signup

行き方

1. メタのお問い合わせフォームでパスワードを忘れたを選択
2. 出現するポップアップからパスワード復元ページへ
3. 「登録」タブをクリック

URL: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/account/recover?recoveryToken=...

1. メタのパスワード復元ページから自分にメールを送る
2. 復元リンクにアクセス

[image: not private]

Google Chrome Version 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit) / Mac OS X 10.10.1

Comment: 開発者と確認しますが、SSLへ移動したのが最近で、URLの構造(metaのサブドメイン）でどうしてもHTTPSがそのエラーを出してしまうと思います。治すにはSEサイトのURL全体の変更になるため、そのままに残ると思います。メインサイトで同じ問題がないと思います。

Comment: 同様の事例をネットワークの別サイトで見かけて、メタSEに投げていました http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254298/286934

Answer (score 2):

いつから治っていたのかは分かりませんが、少なくとも現在スタック・オーバーフローでは [HTTPS がデフォルトになっており](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/22/stack-overflow-flipped-switch-https/)、この問題はもう治っているようでした。